# Why are only some aircraft in this formation creating contrails?

Tags: fighter, turbofan, flying-in-formation, contrails

The Republic Day celebrations at New Delhi, India had a series of flypasts by the [Indian Air Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Air_Force).

What struck me the most was that in a formation with a [C-17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_C-17_Globemaster_III) in middle and two [Su-30MKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukhoi_Su-30MKI) flanking it, there were contrails visible from the Su-30MKI but not from the C-17:

[image: C-17, Su-30MKI Formation on Republic Day 2018]
[image: C-17, Su-30MKI Formation on Republic Day 2018]

Both the C-17 and Su-30MKI have turbofan engines. For C-17, [Pratt & Whitney F117-PW-100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_PW2000) and for Su-30MKI [Lyulka AL-31](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyulka_AL-31).

As per '[How does contrail formation differ from turbofan to turbojet?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/31778)', contrails depend on the bypass ratio of the turbofan engine:

> (...) higher bypass engines available today increase the contrail occurrence.

As per available sources, the F117 has a [bypass ratio of 5.9:1](http://www.pw.utc.com/F117_Engine) and the AL-31 has a [bypass ratio of 0.59:1](http://enacademic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/3621458). So, the F117 has higher bypass compared to the AL-31 (or maybe I'm wrong).

**What would be the reason that in the first two photographs, the C-17 engines do not form contrail whereas the Su-30MKI seem to?**

One possibility is that, this difference is due to possible different power settings on the two aircraft engines for the same speed (considering the different intended role).

Another thing was that such contrails were not visible on any other fighter aircraft (e.g., [Tejas/LCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_Tejas)). Or even another pair of Su-30MKI along with a [AEW&CS aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRDO_AEW%26CS):

[image: Tejas/LCA Formation on Republic Day 2018]
[image: Su-30MKI along with a AEW&CS aircraft]

**Notes:**

1. Sorry for the poor quality of photos due to the poor visibility in Delhi (winter fog/smog).
2. Some photos are here:

   - [thequint.com](https://www.thequint.com/news/hot-news/republic-day-parade-sees-spectacular-flypast-by-iaf-aircraft)
   - [blogs.wsj.com](https://blogs.wsj.com/indiarealtime/2016/01/26/republic-day-parade-indias-military-to-show-off-its-hardware/)
   - [indiatimes.com](https://www.indiatimes.com/news/india/here-s-a-behind-the-scenes-look-at-the-preparations-for-the-republic-day-parade-2018_-338364.html)

Comment: Are you sure that they weren't using some sort of smoke generation system? Those don't look like contrails to me.

Comment: @RonBeyer not sure/aware about smoke generation... But now that you mentioned it, I also doubt these are contrails...

Comment: Absolutely not contrails. Smoke generators for sure. Actual contrails, condensation from the motors, won't form near sa level in warm air.

Comment: And amazingly, in that second pic the Sukhoi's can apparently produce a giant bird in their trails! :D

Comment: They must be chemtrails

Comment: Should be added that the **reason** that aircraft in airshows often leave smoke trails is to aid civilian visibility. People who are not accustomed to "looking up" often have difficultly locating the airplane(s) in the sky.

Comment: Conspiracy theorist would probably claim the jets are fumigating the population, and the C-17 not.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This 'party trick' is covered nicely on [metabunk.org](https://www.metabunk.org/debunked-military-chemtrails-on-off-su-30-smoke-skywriting.t2926/).

> [It's the Su-30's] ability to inject unburnt fuel into the exhaust plume via the afterburner system. The super hot air of the exhaust instantly evaporates the volatile fuel, and then when it mixes with the cold air behind the plane the fuel reforms as a fine mist, essentially a fuel smoke cloud.

[image]([YouTube](https://youtu.be/yzFTOb0K1ZE?t=102))

Comment: Ha, we actually came up with the same source moments apart.

Comment: Seconds apart! :D

Comment: 'party trick' :) Interesting read! +1

Comment: And a +1 for the both of ya's (@Jamiec) for the "great minds think alike" effort.

Comment: Is there any practical reason to do this? Or is it just for cool points?

Comment: That doesn't seem like it would help with the local smog...

Comment: Like the smoke generators on board ships and battle tanks?

Answer (score 31):

From: [Forum post - "Trails from the back of Fighter Jets", *Metabunk.org*](https://www.metabunk.org/trails-from-the-back-of-fighter-jets.t8590/)

> Jets practicing for air-shows (or actually in air-shows) sometimes use smoke to create trails. This is made by injecting something like paraffin into the hot exhaust where it vaporizes and condenses as smoke.

And the accompanying image

[image]

Looks a lot like the image in your question.